# Return the array which has the largest sum. In event of a tie, return a

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

While practicing Java problems on coding bat I came across this problem. Though I have solved this problem, I was wondering if I could get a solution with a fewer if-else statement. Can you help me with this?

**Question:**

Start with two int arrays, a and b, each length 2. Consider the sum of the values in each array. Return the array which has the largest sum. In event of a tie, return a.

Example:-

```
biggerTwo([1, 2], [3, 4]) → [3, 4]
biggerTwo([3, 4], [1, 2]) → [3, 4]
biggerTwo([1, 1], [1, 2]) → [1, 2]
```

**My Solution:-**

```
public int[] biggerTwo(int[] a, int[] b) {
   if(a[0]+a[1]==b[0]+b[1]){
    return a;
  }
  else if(a[0]+a[1]>b[0]+b[1]){
    return a;
  }else{
    
  return b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a ternary operator.

```
return a[0] + a[1] >= b[0] + b[1] ? a : b;
```

Note `>=`. Hence it the event of a tie, `a` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary length array, making use of `>=` operator and of Streams:

```
public int[] maxSum(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return IntStream.of(a).sum() >= IntStream.of(b).sum() ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when comparing multiple arrays of indefinite length.

```
public int[] biggest(int[]... arrays) {
    return Stream.of(arrays)
        .min(Comparator.comparing(array -> IntStream.of(array).sum()))
        .orElse(null);
}
```

If no array is specified in the argument, it returns null.